# Tensorflow custom op -- how do I read and write from Tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm writing a custom Tensorflow op using the tutorial and I'm having trouble understanding how to read and write to/from Tensors.

let's say I have a Tensor in my OpKernel that I get from 
`const Tensor& values_tensor = context->input(0);` (where context = `OpKernelConstruction*`)

if that Tensor has shape, say, [2, 10, 20], how can I index into it (e.g. `auto x = values_tensor[1, 4, 12]`, etc.)?

equivalently, if I have

```
Tensor *output_tensor = NULL;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(
  0,
  {batch_size, value_len - window_size, window_size},
  &output_tensor
));
```

how can I assign to `output_tensor`, like `output_tensor[1, 2, 3] = 11`, etc.?

sorry for the dumb question, but the docs are really tripping me up here and the examples in the Tensorflow kernel code for built-in ops somehow obfuscate this to the point that I get very confused :)

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to read from and write to [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor) objects is to convert them to an [Eigen tensor](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support), using the [`tensorflow::Tensor::tensor<T, NDIMS>()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#tensor_18) method. Note that you have to specify the (C++) type of elements in tensor as template parameter `T`.

For example, to read a particular value from a `DT_FLOAT32` tensor:

```
const Tensor& values_tensor = context->input(0);
auto x = value_tensor.tensor<float, 3>()(1, 4, 12);
```

To write a particular value to a `DT_FLOAT32` tensor:

```
Tensor* output_tensor = ...;
output_tensor->tensor<float, 3>()(1, 2, 3) = 11.0;
```

There are also convenience methods for accessing a [scalar](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#scalar), [vector](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#vec), or [matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#matrix).